# JSF dynamically created form parameters not accurate

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

I am having some strange results when trying to access dynamic data as parameters in listeners. Below is a snippet of my xhtml. I have a backing bean, skillsController.java, and a pojo Skill.java

The ui:repeat is iterating through categories, and generating a dataTable for each one. Visually everything appears to be generating correctly. The problem arises when trying to access the variables that are created in the xhtml at a later time. When using any kind of listener attached to the selectonmenu, the skill variable from the datatable does not match the data used to generate the page initially. For instance the skill used when the form is submitted is linked to data in the first categories skills, rather than the correct category/skill that it should have.

It seems the skills are going out of sync between page generation and form submission. Are there any suggestions on how to get the correct values stored in the skill on form submission?

```
<h:form rendered="#{!skillsController.mode.equalsIgnoreCase('Show My Skills')}">                    
    <ui:repeat var="cat" value="#{skillsController.masterCategories}" varStatus="status">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" rendered="#{cat.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(skillsController.mode)||skillsController.mode.equalsIgnoreCase('Show All Skills')}">
            <h3 class="arSkillsHeader">
                <h:outputLabel value="#{cat.toString()}"
                    style="font-weight:bold" />
            </h3>
            <h:dataTable style="margin-left:15px; margin-right:15px"
                class="suggestionsTable" var="skill"
                rowClasses="gray, lightgraybg"
                columnClasses="null, hCol3, versionCol, null"
                value="#{skillsController.getSkillsByCategory(cat)}">
                <h:column>
                    <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/success.png"
                        style="height:20px"
                        rendered="#{skillsController.hasSkill(cat.toString(), skill.name.toString())}" />
                </h:column>
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{skill.name.toString()}" />                                           
                </h:column> 
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{skill.categoryName}" rendered="false" />
                    <h:outputText value="#{skill.name}" rendered="false" />
                    <h:selectManyCheckbox id = "versionCheckbox"
                                          layout ="lineDirection"
                                          style = "text-align: left;"
                                          value = "#{skill.checkedVersions}"
                                          valueChangeListener="#{skillsController.versionsChecked}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{skillsController.getVersions(skill.getName(), skill.getCategoryName())}"/>
                    </h:selectManyCheckbox> 
                </h:column>             
                <h:column>
                    <h:selectOneMenu id="proficiency" value="#{skill.proficiency}">
                        <f:selectItem
                            itemValue="#{skillsController.timeList.get(0)}"
                            itemLabel="Select Experience Level" />
                        <f:selectItems
                            value="#{skillsController.timeList.subList(1, skillsController.timeList.size())}" />
                        <f:ajax render="versionCheckbox @this"
                                listener="#{skill.proficiencyUpdated(skill.proficiency)}"/>
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
                </h:column>
            </h:dataTable>
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="height:20px">
                <h:commandButton value="Update Category" style="float:right; margin-right:15px;"
                    action="#{skillsController.updateCategorySkills(cat)}"
                    onclick="updatePro(this.id);">
                    <f:ajax execute="@form" render="@form" />
                </h:commandButton>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>                         
    </ui:repeat>
</h:form>
```

Comment: The placement and condition of your `rendered` attribute on the form might be responsible for the erratic behaviour

Comment: By default, all skills are visible, so I would have thought that it would default to that behavior. I have tried removing the rendered attribute, but the issue persists.